# Erro de js em modal(popup)

Tags: php, javascript, html, modal, popup

Minha duvida é sobre um codigo de modal que eu modifiquei porem o js da erro e o modal não abre

essa é a parte html:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <a class="btn trigger" href="javascript:;">Click Me!</a>
 </div>
<div class="modal-wrapper">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="head">
      <a class="btn-close trigger" href="javascript:;"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

e essa é a parte de js que eu coloquei antes do fechamento da tag :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { //erro nessa linha "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
          $('.trigger').click(function() {
             $('.modal-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
            $('.page-wrapper').toggleClass('blur');
             return false;
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Eu tentei modificar mas não esta adiantando muito, sabem o que pode ser?

Comment: Você precisa adicionar o `jquery` na pagina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
          $('.trigger').click(function() {
             $('.modal-wrapper').toggle("open");
             $('.page-wrapper').toggle("blur");
          }); 
              return false; //aqui o return fica fora do click function
        });
```

```css
.modal-wrapper{
  
position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 220px;
  top: 65px;
  background: #12C12B;
 }
  .page-wrapper{
  
position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  background: #12C12B;
 }
```

```html
<!-- essa linha é necessária -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- essa linha é necessária -->

<div class="page-wrapper">
  <a class="btn trigger" href="javascript:;">Click Me!</a>
 </div>
<!-- aqui coloquei sua div como hidden -->
<div class="modal-wrapper" hidden>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="head">
      <a class="btn-close trigger" href="javascript:;"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Oi Day 
adpte como precisar